# why receiving assignment error in for loop?

Tags: c++

I have a class member function as below:

```
int changeBase () 
{

    for (int i=1; getDigit()>0; i*=2, getDigit()/=10)
      {
        s+=(getDigit()%10)*i;
      }
        return s;
}
```

Why do I receive the following error?

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: What is the type of `s`?

Comment: and what does `getDigit()` return? I suspect the problem is `getDigit()/=10` but since you haven't shown the rest f the code this is just guesswork. Please fix your question to show the relevant context, not just a useless snippet of code in isolation.

Comment: if getDigit() doesn't return reference, and from the error I guess it doesn't, you cant assign into it, that is why `getDigit()/=10` is an error.

Comment: On a side note, the `getDigit` function is likely ill-named. If it does what its name suggests, the modulo 10 is useless, and integer dividing by 10 would always return 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last condition of your `for` loop is

```
getDigit() /= 10
```

This is a short-hand way to write

```
getDigit() = getDigit() / 10
```

Which is not valid, you are trying to assign an `int` (I'm assuming) to the returned value of your function, which you cannot do.

Comment: The validity depends on how getDigit is defined (it might return a reference...).

Comment: It could even be valid if `getDigit` were declared as `int &getDigit()`, in which case it would *not* mean `getDigit() = getDigit() / 10`: the function would be called only once.

Comment: Occam's razor. Plus one; this *probably* fixes the issue. Would be rather flashy to have a function returning a reference.